# gwt - dynamic tree structure using uibinder

Tags: gwt

I have a tree structure which has sub nodes and these sub nodes in turn have their own sub nodes.
I now want to add click handlers for the root node and every child node.  Can any one please help me that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to add a ClickHandler to each node. It is very inefficient. You need to add a single SelectionHandler to your tree.

When you create each TreeItem, you can set a user object on this item. In your SelectionHandler, you check what user object is set on the selected item, and then you act accordingly.